# z-index of Bootstrap3 Tooltip in columns is Browser specific

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

Using bootstrap 3 I've got two columns (`sm-3` and `sm-9`). The left column is `position: fixed` and contains a link with a tooltip. The `z-index` of the tooltip (without being specified) seems to be browser specific.

What is (in general) the best way to define the `z-index` of the tooltip? I'm looking for a clean solution that works in all common browsers.

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/p30m8rm3/)**

**Internet Explorer 11** (left) **Chrome 48 / Edge 25** (right)

[image: Internet Explorer 11][image: Chrome]

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-sm-3" id="left">
    <a id="tooltipButton" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title='Long Text'>Show Tooltip</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3" id="right">
    Content
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#left { position: fixed;  }
#right { background-color: #ddd;  }
```

**JS:**

```
$('#tooltipButton').tooltip({
  trigger: 'click',
  html: true,
  placement: 'right',
});
```

**A few things I've tried (CSS):**

```
.tooltip { z-index: 10; } // Doesn't work
.tooltip .tooltip.in { z-index: 10; } // Doesn't work
.tooltip .tooltip-inner { z-index: 10; } // Doesn't work
```

Is there a clean solution without adding more divs and without changing the attributes of the left or right div? E.g. `#left { z-index: 10; }` seems to work but changes the attributes and the overlapping behavior of the left div.

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/p30m8rm3/)**

Comment: you tried adding `!important`?  `.tooltip { z-index: 10 !important; }` ?

Comment: Yes, I tried `!important` for `.tooltip`, `.tooltip.in` and `.tooltip-inner` but it doesn't work. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you give an element a `position` other than static it forces it to appear above any element that is still static. It's a rather unknown behavior of `z-index`. Therefore if a parent element has a `position` other than `static` all it's children will have their own stacking scope. It works almost like layers.

This article has an amazing write up about it: [What no-one told you about z-index](http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/)

So in your example all the tooptip code is appearing in the container that has it's own stacking scope and is therefore forced under the next container. If you add `z-index:999;` to the `#left` container you will see it is fixed. This is because that container (and it's contents) are now forced higher than the next.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/p30m8rm3/1/)

The other thing you could do is remove `position:relative` from the `#right` container so it doesn't have it's own stacking scope and then it works again.

[JSFIDDLE v2](https://jsfiddle.net/p30m8rm3/2/)

I don't think this helps much with your problem as I don't think you can hack you way out of it. It is much more common practice that tooltip code is injected into the bottom of the page so that it naturally stacks above everything else.

Comment: Honestly I was looking for a better solution but I guess there is none. Anyway, I appreciate your work and explanation. Thank you.

Comment: @hurb the position:relative; stacking thing was a massive gotcha for me. Only found out about 2 years ago after working for 10 years in production builds...